# Algorithms about Perigee and Apogee of Moon

Tags: algorithm, astronomy, orbital-mechanics

I am trying to calculate perigee and apogee of the moon.In chapter 48 of the book 《Astronomical algorithms》,there is a sentence that I can't understand,It says:"Sum of the terms in Table 48.A (apogee) = -0.4654".There are 60 terms in Table 48A,is that mean I should add up them all? It seems not to be a good idea.

[image]

Comment: sum of therms is not the same as sum of coefficients ... They are probably multiplied by some parameter(s) or even polynomial first and then summed together. Its hard to say without context and actual text from the book ... btw si it [this book](http://www.agopax.it/Libri_astronomia/pdf/Astronomical%20Algorithms.pdf) ?

Comment: looks like that link I found has it in chapter 50. its as I expected the `argument of sine` is a polynomial of `T,k` so I assume you multiply that polynomial with coefficient ... for each row of your table and then sum the results.

Comment: Thanks every one.I tried to sum all the items and got the same result as the book.
-1.6769 * sin(2*D) + 0.4589 * sin(4*d)+....，It's really a  tedious  job.

Comment: You should add that as answer  ... maybe even wit the code ...